# DOTNET class not found, what does "not present in this build" mean?

Tags: .net, com, php

I have tried installing ZendServer, WampServer, and XAMPP. When I installed ZendServer, my code that instantiates a `new DOTNET()` works. With WampServer and XAMPP, however, it gives me the error "Class 'DOTNET' not found." On those Wamp and XAMPP servers, `phpinfo()` says under the com_dotnet section: ".Net support - not present in this build." **What does this mean?**

I looked into the source and the plot thickens: apparently this message is given when the macro `HAVE_MSCOREE_H` is defined as `true`. But I can find nowhere in the entire source that actually *defines* this value. Confusing.

So, anyone know what it means that .Net support is not present in a build of PHP? The manual page says nothing about it and says that .Net support should be built in and have no installation required.

PS: The Apache website is blocked by my work's proxy server filter, so I couldn't test a vanilla install instead of one of those software packs. Yeah, ridiculous, I know. :)